# Javascript Hover and Toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation

My navigation is hidden and hover is showing but disappearing immediately, I want the navigation to show on hover and `display: none` on mouse out of the element

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#nav-holder").hover(function () {
        $("nav").animate({height: 'toggle'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey u will have to use mouseover and mouseout

Comment: wait will post the code now

Comment: You should provide enough code to replicate the issue. That means including your HTML in the question. It would also be useful to provide a live example, such as a JSFIddle link

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#nav-holder").mouseover(function(argument) {

             $("nav").show();
})

$("#nav-holder").mouseout(function(argument) {

            $("nav").hide();
})

});
```

Comment: Hide will add style to display none.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [`mouseenter`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](https://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) instead of hover:

```
$(function() {
  $("#nav-holder")
    .mouseenter(showNavigation)
    .mouseleave(hideNavigation)
})

function showNavigation() {
  $("nav").show("fast")
}
function hideNavigation() {
  $("nav").hide()
}
```